# How to implement the pressing and holding of a key until another action is performed?

Tags: python, python-keyboard

I want to make a piece of code in which a key is pressed and held until another action is performed. Here is my code:

```
'''
virtual steering wheel 

hold your hand as you hold steering wheel 
turn right 
turn left 
'''

import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import math 
import keyboard

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands

switch_hand = 1
decider = 0


# For webcam input:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_hands.Hands(
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as hands:
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue

    # Flip the image horizontally for a later selfie-view display, and convert
    # the BGR image to RGB.
    image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
    # pass by reference.
    image.flags.writeable = False
    results = hands.process(image)


    # Draw the hand annotations on the image.
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    right_temp = []
    left_temp = []

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
      for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, hand_landmarks, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        
        # x and y cordinates of thumbtip
        if switch_hand == 1:
          right_temp.append([float(hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].x), float(hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].y)])
        
        elif(switch_hand == -1):
          left_temp.append([float(hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].x), float(hand_landmarks.landmark[mp_hands.HandLandmark.WRIST].y)])  

        switch_hand *= -1 

        if(len(right_temp) == 1 or len(left_temp) == 1):
            try:  
              myradians = math.atan2(right_temp[0][1]- left_temp[0][1], right_temp[0][0] - left_temp[0][0])
              mydegrees = int(math.degrees(myradians))
              #print(int(mydegrees))

              if(int(mydegrees > 14) or (-170 < mydegrees <  -160)):
                print("right")
                keyboard.press('d')

              elif(int(mydegrees <-15)):
                print("left")
                keyboard.press('a')
    
              else:
                print("nothing")
                keyboard.release()
            except:
              pass

        
    cv2.imshow('View pannel', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
      break
cap.release()
```

When the code outputs 'right', I want to press and hold the 'd' key as I would do in a physical world, release the key as soon as the code outputted 'left' and vice versa.

The problem with my code is:
    In every single step of the loop it presses and releases a key, similar to pressing a single key multiple times.

Comment: I think you need to keep track of the state of things; if the current state is centered, and then you go into the "right" state, then press "d"; if the current state is "right", and you detect "right" again, then do nothing; if you're in the "right" state and leave that state, then release "d". Same goes for the "left" state. Just draw a flowchart of what you want to have happen, then you can build that logic into your program. Makes sense?

Comment: You tried the above but the keyboard module was "not working"? Please show your attempt then. And can you explain what you mean by the keyboard module not working? I notice you're not releasing a specific key, when the [module's documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardreleasehotkey) says that the `release()` method accepts a key. Not sure if that's your only issue. If you use the state model I was talking about, then you should only have to press one time, rather than every loop iteration, just as I explained.

Comment: I tried this method  but the problem is with  keyboard module it does not have any function that press and hold key  in a global state , and I have done a lot of research for getting a module that keep key pressed in global state

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardpresshotkey), `keyboard.press(hotkey)` "Presses and holds down a hotkey". So are you saying their documentation is wrong? I think it's more likely that you're not using or understanding the module correctly. Please show a [mre] of the issue you're talking about, where it's not pressing and holding the key. Try doing it using really simple code, not even with OpenCV or anything, but just simple code that attempts to give the behavior you eventually want.

Comment: I though about your approach found that in order to change key( lets say from right to left) i need to run this piece of code again( keyboad.press('a') ) , but the code its self will get stuck at while loop and hence will not able to run that code in global state in order to change key